# Disabling a button in a gridview that's populated from a select in another gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here's the scenario. I have 2 gridviews.
Gridview 1 is like this for example

```
 __________________________________
| select | cell 2 | cell 3         |
```

Then when you click on the select in cell 1 it populates Gridview 2.

```
  _______________________________
 | cell 1 | cell 2 | BUTTON      |
```

And then when the second gridview loads up I am trying to disabled the button if the value in cell 2 is true.

I've tried to disable the button using the rowdatabound event.
Grabbing the cell text info with the following.

On the aspx page

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView10" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                Font-Size="10px" CellPadding="2" 
                DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource35" Width="100%" 
                BorderColor="#CCCCCC" OnRowCommand="GridView10_RowCommand" 
                onrowdatabound="GridView10_RowDataBound"
```

in code behind

```
protected void GridView10_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string cellt = e.Row.Cells[5].Text;

    if (cellt == "True")
    {
        Button btn = (Button)e.Row.Cells[6].Controls[1];
        btn.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Normally this works just spiffy. But for whatever reason the event doesn't seem to be firing in this scenario. Anyone has any insight into this issue?

Comment: So you're saying the RowDataBound event you've shown doesn't fire at all?  Is that event attached to the GridView declaritively (in the markup) or programmatically (in the code behind)?

Comment: You can use a templatefield and just set Enabled on the button = `<%# Eval("dbColumnThatPopulatesSecondGridViewColumn").ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Equals("True") %>`

Comment: Judging by the code you copied in the onrowdatabound isn't being picked up by intellisense .... could be as easy as fixing the casing to OnRowDataBound

Comment: @urbanlemur Oddly enough, those event delegate properties are not case-sensitive (though the actual Control properties *are*).

Comment: urbanlemur: Good eye man. That did the trick. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the correct Gridview cell?
You might be using the wrong cell ID Where

```
protected void GridView10_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string cellt = e.Row.Cells[CORRECT CELL?].Text;

     if (cellt == "True")
    {
        Button btn = (Button)e.Row.Cells[CORRECT CELL?].Controls[1];
        btn.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

If this is the correct cell, You can just change the visibility property

Buttonname.visible = false

Also,
You can do this

```
protected void GridView10_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        string cellt = e.Row.Cells[CORRECT CELL?].Tostring;
         if (cellt != "True") continue;
        {
            Button btn = (Button)e.Row.Cells[CORRECT CELL?].Controls[1];
            buttonname.visible = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Remember gridviews start from cell 0

So if you have it as cell 6 , make sure you're starting from cell 0 - so cell 6 might be cell 5..

EDIT, I've noticed your asking if a cell has a specific text, Use .Tostring shown above.